# Gihub error occuring when i am push or pull my code via vscode

Tags: github, push, pull

The error occurs when i am push or pull my code  in github and the error says this -
`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<your-github-account>/<git-repo-name>/': Could not resolve host: github.com` 
how can we solve this error ??

Answer (score -1):

The answer lies within the following image:

[image]

All I done was sign-in again and this helped me to resume my account in browser that was paused and mainly from where GitHub use that browser to open your GitHub!

**Important**: Make sure your account you sign-in again is your same account which you had add as `git --config global user.email` otherwise it browser won't allow to access your GitHub as manual sign-in is required!

Comment: No, this is not the answer. Your question is just a simple network issue.